# Count how many times a time occurs within a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I could not think of a good way to phrase this question to search properly if its already been asked.

I'm looking for a way in SQL 2008 R2 to count how many times 6pm occurs between two datetime values.

For example between **'2017-04-17 19:00:00'** and **'2017-04-19 17:00:00'** 6pm only occurs once even though the times span 3 different days.

Between **'2017-04-17 18:00:00'** and **'2017-04-19 18:00:00'** it occurs 3 times whilst also spanning 3 days.

Heres a really silly made up expression of what I want for illustration.

```
timecount(hh, 6, min(datefield), max(datefield))
```

Thank you

Comment: how about if you have a long date range like month or year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query to count:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2017-04-17 18:00:00'

DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2017-04-19 18:00:00'

SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN CAST(@StartDate AS time) <= '18:00' AND CAST(@EndDate AS time) >= '18:00' 
             THEN datediff(day, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
      WHEN CAST(@StartDate AS time) <= '18:00' AND CAST(@EndDate AS time) < '18:00' 
             THEN datediff(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)      
      WHEN CAST(@StartDate AS time) > '18:00' AND CAST(@EndDate AS time) >= '18:00' 
             THEN datediff(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)
      ELSE datediff(day, @StartDate, @EndDate) - 1
   END AS TotalCount
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you each hour and the number of occurences:

```
select datepart(hh, DateColumn) as TheHours, count(*) as occurs
from MyTable
where DateColumn between @SomeDate and @SomeOtherDate
group by datepart(hh, DateColumn)
```

Or just for 6pm:

```
select count(*)
from MyTable
where datepart(hh, DateColumn) = 18
and DateColumn between @SomeDate and @SomeOtherDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE 
    @Time time = '18:00',
    @From datetime = '2017-04-17 18:00:00',
    @To datetime = '2017-04-19 18:00:00'


SELECT 
    CASE 
        -- Same date
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, @From, @To) = 0 THEN 
            CASE WHEN CAST(CAST(@From AS date) AS datetime) + @Time BETWEEN @From AND @To THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        -- Not same date
        WHEN @From <= @To THEN
            CASE WHEN @Time >= CAST(@From AS time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
            + DATEDIFF(DAY, @From, @To) - 1
            + CASE WHEN @Time <= CAST(@To AS time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        -- Invalid range
        ELSE 0
    END AS CountOfTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula I have tried with different scenario and it works, let me know if I miss any scenario and not work as per your requirement.

```
DECLARE @firstDate Datetime='17-Apr-2017 17:00:00'
DECLARE @secondDate Datetime='17-Apr-2017 18:59:00'


SELECT
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,@firstDate,@secondDate)=0
    THEN IIF(CAST(@firstDate AS TIME) <='18:00' AND DATEPART(hh,@secondDate) >=18,1,0)
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN 
            (
                CAST(@firstDate AS TIME) <='18:00' AND CAST(@secondDate AS TIME) <'18:00' 
                OR
                CAST(@firstDate AS TIME) >'18:00' AND CAST(@secondDate AS TIME) >='18:00' 
            )
            THEN DATEDIFF(day,@firstDate,@secondDate)
            WHEN CAST(@firstDate AS TIME) <='18:00' AND CAST(@secondDate AS TIME) >='18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(day,@firstDate,@secondDate)+1 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(day,@firstDate,@secondDate)-1
            END
    END AS TotalCount
```

Comment: Hi, i'm getting syntax errors with this but can't quite figure out what it is

    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
    Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: not possible, working with my SQL , I just test again

Comment: Anything is possible :), maybe different SQL versions I don't know.

Comment: : -) that may be issue, any way you got answer

Comment: I think not server issue, because error you shown is not related to version

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script, using `CTE`

```
DECLARE @F_DATE     AS DATETIME =   '2017-04-17 19:00:00'
        ,@T_DATE    AS DATETIME =   '2017-04-19 17:00:00'


;WITH CTE
AS  (
    SELECT  (CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH,@F_DATE) <= 18
                THEN @F_DATE 
                ELSE (CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(DAY,@F_DATE,@T_DATE) > 0 
                        THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,@F_DATE) END)
             END)   AS  CDATE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)    <=  @T_DATE
)

SELECT COUNT(CDATE) DATE_COUNT 
FROM CTE
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Comment: CTE has some flows: maxrecursion depth and performance. It's better to avoid using CTE until there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the count of every 6pm between two datetime:**

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
set @StartDate = '2017-04-17 19:00:00'
set @EndDate = '2017-04-19 17:00:00'

;WITH cte1 (S) AS (
SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (S)
),
cte2 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte1 AS cte2),
cte3 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte2 AS cte2)

select count(datepart(hour,result)) as count from
(SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(hour, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
        result = DATEADD(hour, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S) - 1, @StartDate)
FROM cte3) as res where datepart(hour,result) = 18
```

**Here's the detailed view of 6pm between two datetime:**

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
set @StartDate = '2017-04-17 19:00:00'
set @EndDate = '2017-04-19 17:00:00'

;WITH cte1 (S) AS (
SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (S)
),
cte2 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte1 AS cte2),
cte3 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte2 AS cte2)

select result,datepart(hour,result)  from
(SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(hour, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
        result = DATEADD(hour, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S) - 1, @StartDate)
FROM cte3) as res where datepart(hour,result) = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Here gives the count between any date ranges

```
declare @time datetime='06:00:00'

declare @startDate datetime='04/20/2017 05:00:00'

declare @enddate datetime='04/21/2017 05:00:00'

SELECT 
  case 
    WHEN datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@startDate)) <=0  and   datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@enddate)) >=0

     THEN datediff(dd,@startDate,@enddate) +1 
WHEN   (datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@startDate)) <=0  and 
datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@enddate)) <=0

        OR
        datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@startDate))> 0  and 

datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@enddate)) >0

        OR

        datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@startDate))> 0  and datediff(ss,@time, convert(time(0),@enddate)) <=0
        )
then  datediff(dd,@startDate,@enddate) 
ELSE  
datediff(dd,@startDate,@enddate)-1
END
```